# Java - Comparing classes?

Tags: java, android, class, comparison

How can i compare 2 classes?

The following if statement never passes although class is type of MyClass:

```
public void(Class class) {
   if (class == MyClass.class){

   }
}
```

Comment: I doubt it compiles at all... on the other hand if it's just pseudocode, then I don't see anything weird. Can you paste the actual code?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
if (clazz.equals(MyClass.class)) {

}
```

BTW, class is a reserved word.

Comment: `klass` is also a common var name.

Comment: `final Class<E> SAN_DIEGO`

Answer (score 11):

To test whether `clazz` is a (sub) type of `MyClass` do

```
MyClass.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)
```

From the javadoc for [`Class.isAssignableFrom`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter. It returns true if so; otherwise it returns false. If this Class object represents a primitive type, this method returns true if the specified Class parameter is exactly this Class object; otherwise it returns false.
>
> Specifically, this method tests whether the type represented by the specified Class parameter can be converted to the type represented by this Class object via an identity conversion or via a widening reference conversion. See The Java Language Specification, sections 5.1.1 and 5.1.4 , for details.

So

```
Object.class.isAssignableFrom(String.class)
```

is true because each `String` is also an `Object` but

```
String.class.isAssignableFrom(Object.class)
```

is false because not all `Object`s are `String`s.

---

The name "`isAssignableFrom`" comes from the fact that,

```
Class1 x = (Class2) null;
```

is only legal when

```
Class1.class.isAssignableFrom(Class2.class)
```

I.e., we can **assign** a field or variable with static type `Class1` a value that comes **from** an expression whose static type is `Class2`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `==` or `.equals()` to compare `Class` objects.

Example:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        MyClass m = new MyClass();
        if (MyClass.class == m.getClass())
        {
            System.out.println("it worked");
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/AwbNT

Answer (score 6):

You can use `instanceof` operator to check if an instance belongs to a specific class or its subclasses.

```
class MyClass{}

class SubClass extends MyClass{}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    SubClass object = new SubClass();

    if (object instanceof MyClass) {
        System.out.println("It works, too");
    }
}
```